# Filter TreeView JavaFX FilterableTreeItem List Strings

Tags: java, javafx, filter, treeview

I tried to use the following code ( example )

I'm using `FilterableTreeItem` class to filter

```java
public class TreeFromPaths extends Application {

    private final List<String> paths = Arrays.asList(
        //"input1",
        "Registrations.People",
        "Querys.sub2",
        "Reports.sub2.subsub1",
        "Miscellaneous.sub3",
        "input3",
        "input3.sub1",
        "input3.sub1.subsub1",
        "input3.sub1.subsub1.subsubsub1",
        "input3.sub2"
    );

    private <S,T> TreeView<T> createTree(
            List<S> paths, 
            Function<S, ? extends Iterable<T>> pathSplitter, 
            T rootValue) {

        TreeItem<T> root = new TreeItem<>(rootValue);
        populateTree(paths, pathSplitter, root);
        TreeView<T> tree = new TreeView<>(root);
        tree.setShowRoot(false);
        return tree;
    }

    private <S,T> void populateTree(
            List<S> paths, 
            Function<S, ? extends Iterable<T>> pathSplitter, 
            TreeItem<T> root) {

        for (S path : paths) {
            TreeItem<T> current = root ;
            for (T component : pathSplitter.apply(path)) {
                current = getOrCreateChild(current, component);
            }
        }
    }

    private <T> TreeItem<T> getOrCreateChild(TreeItem<T> parent, T value) {
        for (TreeItem<T> child : parent.getChildren()) {
            if (value.equals(child.getValue())) {
                return child ;
            }
        }
        TreeItem<T> newChild = new TreeItem<>(value);
        parent.getChildren().add(newChild);
        return newChild ;
    }

   ...
}
```

TextField filter to scroll through the filter

```java
FilterableTreeItem<String> root = new FilterableTreeItem<>(new String("root"));
paths.forEach(actor -> root.getInternalChildren().add(new FilterableTreeItem<>(actor)));
  
root.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    if (filterField.getText() == null || filterField.getText().isEmpty())
        return null;
    return TreeItemPredicate.create(actor -> actor.toString().contains(filterField.getText()));
}, filterField.textProperty()));
```

it can find it but without updating the treeview.

The strange thing is that if you use a Bean, the filter will run. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `FilterableTreeItem`? Is it your own class or is it from a library? Because it's not in standard JavaFX.

Comment: Hi, Slaw ! https://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/tree/demos/org.eclipse.fx.ui.controls.sample/src/org/eclipse/fx/ui/controls/sample/FilterableTreeItemSample.java

Comment: @JoseTeixeira, I followed the example in the link you posted. Everything works fine and I was able to perform the search. One problem in your code is that you might be initializing the root twice. `root = new FilterableTreeItem(...)`. Also, you didn't share the path splitter in your code.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1):

Search is not performed because you're creating tree items using `new TreeItem<>(value)`. In order to make the tree filterable from the root down, you should create the children using `new FilterableTreeItem<>(value)`. Note that you have to use `getInternalChildren()` instead of `getChildren()` when adding new items, otherwise an exception will be thrown (`FilterableTreeItem` replaces the implementation of children using reflection to enable filtering. Check the [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/tree/bundles/runtime/org.eclipse.fx.ui.controls/src/org/eclipse/fx/ui/controls/tree/FilterableTreeItem.java)).

Working code:

```java
private <S,T> TreeView<T> createTree(List<S> paths, Function<S, ? extends Iterable<T>> pathSplitter, T rootValue) {
    FilterableTreeItem<T> root = new FilterableTreeItem<>(rootValue);
    populateTree(paths, pathSplitter, root);
    TreeView<T> tree = new TreeView<>(root);
    tree.setShowRoot(false);
    return tree;
}

private <S, T> void populateTree(List<S> paths, Function<S, ? extends Iterable<T>> pathSplitter, FilterableTreeItem<T> root) {
    for (S path : paths) {
        FilterableTreeItem<T> current = root ;
        for (T component : pathSplitter.apply(path)) {
            current = getOrCreateChild(current, component);
        }
    }
}

private <T> FilterableTreeItem<T> getOrCreateChild(FilterableTreeItem<T> parent, T value) {
    for (TreeItem<T> child : parent.getInternalChildren()) {
        if (value.equals(child.getValue())) {
            return (FilterableTreeItem<T>) child;
        }
    }
    FilterableTreeItem<T> newChild = new FilterableTreeItem<>(value);
    parent.getInternalChildren().add(newChild);
    return newChild;
}
```

Assuming that your path splitter splits paths by `.`, here is what a demo filterable tree looks like:
[image]

Comment: Hi Chanandler!
I used your code. But, the filter **TreeItemPredicate.create(actor -> pathSplitter.toString().contains(filterField.getText()));**                                                  it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you use `pathSplitter.toString().contains(…)`? It should be `actor.contains(…)`.

Comment: I followed your source code advice. However, it does not filter. Is it possible for you to share your source?

Comment: Where is that part in my code?

Comment: Filter when typing TextField: filterField.getText() . . .

Comment: @JoseTeixeira update your question to show that part and then we can check the problem.